# Remove space when LESS variable value to string

Tags: less

Below is example less mixin code

```
.mixin(@option) {
  .set(@options) when (@options = a){
    @type: linear;
  }

  .set(@option);

  background: -webkit-~'@{type}'-gradient(...);
}
```

The output

```
background: -webkit- linear -gradient(...);
```

How can i remove the space around `linear`?

Comment: See my answer below. Though if you're creating a vendor-prefixing mixins library, don't. Discover and use Autoprefixer ([1](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer), [2](https://github.com/less/less-plugin-autoprefix) or whatever [else](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#usage) suitable AP wrapper for your build enviroment). Nowadays there's absolutely no need for that ancient vendorizing hacks and the unreadable cryptomagic code they enforce.

Comment: your answer work, and really thanks for your suggest :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Less does not support an inplace concatenation via variable interpolation in value statements. You need a temporary variable for this (+ an auxiliary variable in this particular case to handle parens), e.g.:

```
@end-func: ~')';

div {
    @func: ~'-webkit-@{type}-gradient(';
    background: @func ... @end-func;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

[less function]

```
.transition(@propValue) {

    -moz-transition: e(%("-moz-%a", @propValue));

    -webkit-transition: e(%("-webkit-%a", @propValue));

    -ms-transition: e(%("-ms-%a", @propValue));

    transition: @propValue;

}
```

[css]

```
.transition(e("transform 0.5s ease"));
```

[The output]

```
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease;

-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;

-ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.5s ease;

transition: transform 0.5s ease;
```